Android Compose PreviewView Bitmap is null, even if the preview is working
I am working on a specialized industrial device running Andoid 7.1
I want to make screenshots of the camera preview (to jpg) into the cache storage, when an event happens on the device (that event it is triggering a LaunchedEffect block).
My current code looks like this:
@Composable
fun CameraScreen() {

    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val lifecycle = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
    val ctx = LocalContext.current
    val vm = viewModel<MyViewModel>()

    var cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider
    var cameraPreviewView = PreviewView(ctx).apply {
        this.scaleType = scaleType
        layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        )
        implementationMode = PreviewView.ImplementationMode.COMPATIBLE
    }

    val imageCapture by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            ImageCapture.Builder()
                .setJpegQuality(80)
                .setResolutionSelector(
                    ResolutionSelector.Builder()
                        .setResolutionStrategy(
                            ResolutionStrategy(
                                Size(640, 480),
                                ResolutionStrategy.FALLBACK_RULE_CLOSEST_HIGHER_THEN_LOWER
                            )
                        )
                        .setAspectRatioStrategy(AspectRatioStrategy.RATIO_4_3_FALLBACK_AUTO_STRATEGY)
                        .build()
                )
                .setCaptureMode(CAPTURE_MODE_MINIMIZE_LATENCY)
                .build()
        )
    }

    LaunchedEffect(vm.eventHappened) {
        if (vm.eventHappened) {
            val bitmap = cameraPreviewView.bitmap  // !!! HERE BITMAP IS ALWAYS NULL
            if (bitmap != null) {
                saveBitmapImageToFile(vm.photoFile, bitmap)
            }
        }
    }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {

        AndroidView(
            modifier = Modifier.width(pixelToDp(640)).height(pixelToDp(480)),
            factory = { context ->
                val previewUseCase = Preview.Builder()
                    .build()
                    .also {
                        it.surfaceProvider = cameraPreviewView.surfaceProvider
                    }

                coroutineScope.launch {
                    val cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(ctx)
                    cameraProviderFuture.addListener({
                        cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
                        val cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
                            .apply {
                               requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
                            }.build()
                        cameraProvider.unbindAll()
                        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(lifecycle, cameraSelector, previewUseCase, imageCapture)
                    }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(ctx))
                }
                cameraPreviewView
            }
        )
    }
}



The camera preview works with no problems, but when the vm.eventHappened is triggered, the bitmap returned from the cameraPreviewView is null.
I have also tried calling cameraPreviewView.drawToBitmap() but that crashes with exception saying View needs to be laid out before calling drawToBitmap()
Thanks for all the help.

You need to wrap the cameraProviderView in a remember function like this:
val cameraPreviewView by remember { 
        mutableStateOf(
            PreviewView(ctx).apply {
                this.scaleType = scaleType
                layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                )
                implementationMode = PreviewView.ImplementationMode.COMPATIBLE
            }
        )
    }


It did not help unfortunately.

The only working solution was to use ImageAnalysis instead of ImageCapture
val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
    .setTargetResolution(Size(640, 480)) 
    .setBackpressureStrategy(ImageAnalysis.STRATEGY_KEEP_ONLY_LATEST)
    .build()

imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(cameraExecutor, ImageAnalysis.Analyzer { imageProxy ->
     if (vm.takePhoto) {
         vm.lastPhoto = imageProxy.toBitmap()
         vm.takePhoto = false
     }
     imageProxy.close()
})

cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(lifecycle, cameraSelector, previewUseCase, imageAnalysis)

